# InputMismatchException while using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Lately, I tested myself against java, so I don't have much experience. That's why I don't really know what to do with that error. Now to be more precise, The code below is working perfectly on some random android java compiler yet after compiling it with command prompt or Eclipse, the working part ends at the scanner. The program completely ignores the first try to implement input and the second one is rewarded with this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
at Kalkulator.main(Kalkulator.java:14)
```

The code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Kalkulator{
public static void main(String[] args){
double a,b;
System.out.println("wprowadz 2 liczby");
System.out.println("\"format:(x, x)\"");
Scanner dane = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*"); 
a = dane.nextDouble();
b = dane.nextDouble();  
System.out.println("\n"+"Podałeś "+a+" oraz "+b+".");
if (a%2 == 0){
System.out.println("\n"+a +" text");
}
else{
System.out.println("\n"+a +" text");
}
if (b%2 == 0){
System.out.println(b +" text");
}
else{
System.out.println(b +" text");
}   
double  wieksza, mniejsza;
if (a > b){
wieksza = a; mniejsza = b;
}   
else {
wieksza = b; mniejsza = a;
}
System.out.println("Liczbą większą jest "+wieksza);
System.out.println("Liczbą mniejszą jest "+mniejsza);
dane.close ();
}
}`
```

Comment: You called `nextDouble()` and the next input is not parseable as a `double`.  If the input is on two separate lines you need to call `nextLine()` to move to the next input line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using lists:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Kalkulator {
  public static void main(final String... args) {
    System.out.println("enter any number of doubles, whitespace delimited. enter a non-double token to quit");
    final List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<>();
    try (final Scanner dane = new Scanner(System.in)) {
      while (dane.hasNextDouble()) {
        final double input = dane.nextDouble();
        doubles.add(input);
        System.out.println(String.format("Read [%f]", input));
      }
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("finished reading user input. %d doubles read.", doubles.size()));
    System.out.println(String.format("Largest input: %f", doubles.stream().reduce(Math::max).orElse(0D)));
    System.out.println(String.format("Smallest input: %f", doubles.stream().mapToDouble(d -> d).min().orElse(0D)));
  }
}
```